# War obfuscation using DashO

Tags: java, jsp, war, obfuscation

I am using DashO 6.10 for obfuscation of my war files. While obfuscating the war file, **DashO is not taking into consideration the JSP files which have references to some Java files**. As DashO renames the Java files, I am hitting class not found exception from JSPs.

Also, its difficult to add all the referenced Java files(from JSPs) into entry points, as references are more.

Is there any thing that I am missing or DashO does not support this use case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

DashO does not currently analyze the .jsp files.  You would need to manually add what is used by the .jsp files as non-renamed entrypoints.  You can always contact support if you need more information.

Comment: Yeah, I have added those files inside entry-points section of .dox file.